# OAuth requests to Google in embedded browsers

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, awesomium

In the coming months, Google will no longer allow OAuth requests in embedded browsers. In our projects we are using Awesomium as a web component and I actually do not know If this change will also affect our services. Google says:

> Starting October 20, 2016, we will prevent new OAuth clients from
>   using web-views on platforms with a viable alternative, and will phase
>   in user-facing notices for existing OAuth clients.

Now I do not see any `user-facing notices`. Could anyone tell me how them looks like? How can I test my services if they are ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently we're only seeing them in iOS embedded views on Google's "consent page." The consent page is where you have accept the application's request to access your Google user information.

[The blog post you cited above](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html) has been updated to say, "On March 1, 2017 we will post the same notification on the Android consent page."

We've been able to simulate it internally by spoofing the user-agent from the web views.

FWIW, the page also indicates this is going to break for macOS and Windows applications too, but there's no indication of any dates for messaging.

Here's a sample image of the messaging:

[image: Google embedded browser OAuth notice]

Comment: "We've been able to simulate it internally by spoofing the user-agent from the web views" Does that mean that you could work around it by spoofing user agent too?

Comment: @StilgarISCA could you tell us what is the user-agent that was used to simulate this scenario?

Comment: I think it was just iOS 9 or 10. We are not counting on this to continue working with any user agent string and have started going through the rather painful process of changing how the desktop and mobile clients authenticate.

Comment: I noticed today that Google has started teasing that they're going to have a "new" login page in the coming weeks. I can't help but think this is going to coincide with their retirement of embedded web views.
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7338427

Comment: It looks like Google has started disabling in-app OAuth logins. One of my coworkers ran into this page trying to authenticate in someone else's app:
https://www.screencast.com/t/WeJZle9gW9h